# Is it a way to make bluetooth pairing much faster

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth, bluez, rfcomm

Goal: trying to achieve fast Bluetooth pairing.

Storyline: I tried Bluecove library in Java, and if you know already the device address, pairing process on windows is blindly fast. On Linux it is lacking 15 seconds or so and is pretty annoying. Therefore I tried to use BlueZ library in order to create my own driver in C. Let's consider that the destination address is already known (so the problem is not the discovering of the device itself).

I am opening a socket

```
scoket s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);
```

Setting everything into a sockaddr_rc object, then try to connect to the device.

```
int status = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
```

Even if status is zero (which is fine, it means connection is done) the connect call itself take between 6 and 10 seconds.

Is it a way to lower this connection time?

Thank you!

Comment: apparently socket creation is the most expensive component, and I do not found yet a way to lower its time. Is consuming 90% from total execution time ... Any idea about this?